# Is the character "&" alone illegal in HTML 4.01 Strict documents?

Tags: html

I always saw statements to not use `&` in HTML documents by itself, and use `&amp;` instead.

So I tried putting `&` in the title and in the content of the page, but they validate:

http://topics2look.com/code-examples/HTML/ampersand-by-itself-can-validate.html

Is `&` by itself legal in HTML 4.01 Strict documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [W3C HTML 4.01 Strict Charset section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html) says

> Four character entity references
>   deserve special mention since they are
>   frequently used to escape special
>   characters:
>
> ```
> * "&lt;" represents the < sign.
> * "&gt;" represents the > sign.
> * "&amp;" represents the & sign.
> * "&quot; represents the " mark.
> ```
>
> Authors wishing to put the "<"
>   character in text should use "<"
>   (ASCII decimal 60) to avoid possible
>   confusion with the beginning of a tag
>   (start tag open delimiter). Similarly,
>   authors should use ">" (ASCII
>   decimal 62) in text instead of ">" to
>   avoid problems with older user agents
>   that incorrectly perceive this as the
>   end of a tag (tag close delimiter)
>   when it appears in quoted attribute
>   values.
>
> Authors should use "&amp;" (ASCII
>   decimal 38) instead of "&" to avoid
>   confusion with the beginning of a
>   character reference (entity reference
>   open delimiter). Authors should also
>   use "&amp;" in attribute values since
>   character references are allowed
>   within CDATA attribute values.

As it uses the word "should" instead of "must", I guess you can skip it and still validate.

But don't do  that, because it will sometimes render oddly.

I actually had to escape a couple of the ampersands in my cut-paste of this quote to get SO to render the character entity text... ;-)

Comment: Also, the section on Ampersands in URI Attribute values is related: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2 .

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's an error or not in HTML 4 depends on whether it's an error or not in SGML. I can't check that since the spec is not publicly accessible. The HTML 4 spec does imply it's not an error («Authors should use "&"» uses "should", not "must").

It's an error in HTML 4's XML serialisation (XHTML) for it is an error in XML («CharData ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)»)

It's not an error in HTML 5's HTML serialialisation. («Not a character reference. No characters are consumed, and nothing is returned. (This is not an error, either.)»)

It's an error in HTML 5's XML serialisation for it's invalid in XML («CharData ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)»)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is legal.

**It's legal in HTML 4.01, and is also legal in the HTML 4 Strict doctype**, because it is not one of the deprecated features such as the FONT tag.

**It is not legal in any version of XHTML**.  The reason is that by definition XHTML must be XML compliant and the unescaped ampersand has a special meaning in the spec (for entities).

When possible it's preferable to use XHTML because it's a tighter, more modern spec, and more info can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML.  Usually HTML is used for legacy support.

I understand HTML is still used for practical reasons in many places, and in this case **it is considered a best practice to use the escaped version, even though it is in fact legal** in your doctype.

An ampersand "by itself" is called an "unescaped ampersand" if you ever want to search more on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve researched this thoroughly and wrote about my findings here: **http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands**

I’ve also created [an online tool](http://mothereff.in/ampersands) that you can use to check your markup for ambiguous ampersands or character references that don’t end with a semicolon, both of which are invalid. (No HTML validator currently does this correctly.)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyGPK.png]